# (javascript) local storage value -> Can I change the order of the objects?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I set the data to a key called 'todo' in Local Storage.

The structure is like this.

```
key: todo
value : [{"text":"text1","idx":1, "complete":"Y"},
        {"text":"text2","idx":2, "complete":"N"},
        {"text":"text4","idx":4, "complete":"Y"}]
```

My to-do list can be deleted and changed between 'complete' and 'incomplete' status.
I want to change the order of to-do to the bottom when it is completed.

For example,
`{"text": "text1", "idx": 1, "complete": "Y"}`
When the "complete" value of this object has changed to "N".
(`{"text": "text1", "idx": 1, "complete": "N"}`)

I want this result.

```
key: todo
value : [{"text":"text4","idx":4, "complete":"Y"},
        {"text":"text2","idx":2, "complete":"N"},
        {"text":"text1","idx":1, "complete":"N"}]
```

The completed to-do wants to appear at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom sort function `Array.prototype.sort(function(){})`

```js
let tasks = {
  key: "todo",
  value: [{
      "text": "text1",
      "idx": 1,
      "complete": "Y"
    },
    {
      "text": "text2",
      "idx": 2,
      "complete": "N"
    },
    {
      "text": "text4",
      "idx": 4,
      "complete": "Y"
    }
  ]
};

tasks.value.sort((a1, a2) => {
  if (a1.complete == "Y") {
    if (a2.complete == "Y")
      return 0;
    else
      return -1;

  } else {
    if (a2.complete == "Y")
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;


  }
})

console.log(tasks);
```